# How to use TensorFlow GPU if anaconda is installed in D-Drive?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, gpu

I am running out of space in C Drive. Currently, Anaconda is installed in C drive but I want to re-install it in D Drive. I tried it but TensorFlow is not able to detect the GPU. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is probably an NTFS junction - the path of Anaconda can remain unchanged starting with `C:` but the files would physically be on `D:`.